# Show excel data in html without any server

Tags: javascript, html, excel, xls

I have an XLS file with data in it.
The excel file has a lot of reference in one column, so I want the user to type the reference then the web page search for the reference and show the data in the line found.

I can't use a server, so I want to do it without PHP or things like that.

Is it possible ? How can I do that ?

Thanks

Comment: Save the file to HTML and the user can use Ctrl+F...

Comment: No I need to show it in a web page and the data are not all at the same place so it needs to be simpler for the user. I know there is things like PHPExcel but it needs a server

Comment: You can use javascript if you know how to write that.

Comment: What you mean "a lot of reference"? For JavaScript, you may try [js-xlsx](https://github.com/SheetJS/js-xlsx), it work without server.

Answer (score 0):

You **don't** need PHP but at least [Javascript](http://www.w3schools.com/js/).

You can do it like this:

```
var excel = new ActiveXObject("Excel.Application");
var wb = excel.Workbooks.Open("Path/to/your/excel/file.xls");
var ws = wb.ActiveSheet;
var cell = ws.Cells.Find("your search input");
alert(cell.Row);
excel.Quit();
```

I hope i could help you;)

Comment: I just tried it, It works on IE but my problem is I also use sessionStorage for avoid using database and IE is not compatible with it so I use firefox to access the web app and I can find activ x plugin for firefox.

Comment: Take note: you should never offer to send someone the full code. If you have more code relevant to the question, you should post it here. Private messaging the code doesn't help future users.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the sample of js-xlsx, and will return all values in all worksheets as JSON object, you may need to modify by your usage.

```
<html>
<script src="xlsx.core.min.js"></script>
<head></head>
<body>
</body>
<script type ="text/javascript">

    "use strict";

    var X = XLSX;

    function convertFile(b64data) {
        var wb = X.read(b64data, {type: 'base64',WTF: false});

        var result = {};
        wb.SheetNames.forEach(function(sheetName) {
            var roa = X.utils.sheet_to_row_object_array(wb.Sheets[sheetName]);
            if(roa.length > 0){
                result[sheetName] = roa;
            }
        });

        return JSON.stringify(result, 2, 2);
    }
</script>
</html>
```

More option (by upload file, drag and drop option), you can study the source code of js-xlsx example: http://oss.sheetjs.com/js-xlsx/